# Save UserState on Swipe in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android

In my application I have FragmentStatePagerAdapter that has a series of 11 Fragments. I have disabled the swipe on the view pager and only navigation is a through a series of arrows on each fragment. Now on each fragment the user types some input and on pressing the next arrow FragmentStatePagerAdapter resolved and replaced the next Fragment.

1. What would be the best way to save the input of the user via the Fragment lifecycle, so if the user comes back to the same Fragment, the input is the again restored ? I presume `onSaveInstanceState` and using onCreate to restore the input via the `Bundle` ?
2. Will the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` call the above methods automatically ?
3. What other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are destroyed completely when you move to another fragment. So you have to store the user input to somewhere like SharedPreferences or SQLite database. After that, just override `onCreateView` method and restore the user input if it's stored.